# rgdal / readOGR - unable to read shapefile from .zip

Tags: r, ggplot2, gis, rgdal

I'm trying to load a zip level shapefile to do some plotting, per:
https://github.com/hadley/ggplot2/wiki/plotting-polygon-shapefiles
http://www.nceas.ucsb.edu/scicomp/usecases/ReadWriteESRIShapeFiles 
etc

My code:

```
library(rgdal)
library(RColorBrewer)
library(ggplot2)
zipmap = readOGR(dsn="file.zip/", layer="myZIPmap")
```

I'm getting this error:

```
Error in ogrInfo(dsn = dsn, layer = layer, input_field_name_encoding = input_field_name_encoding) : 
  Cannot open file
```

I checked the drivers but to be honest am not able to interpret the output:

```
ogrDrivers()
             name write
1      AeronavFAA FALSE
2          ARCGEN FALSE
3          AVCBin FALSE
4          AVCE00 FALSE
5             BNA  TRUE
6             CSV  TRUE
7             DGN  TRUE
8             DXF  TRUE
9          EDIGEO FALSE
10 ESRI Shapefile  TRUE
11     Geoconcept  TRUE
12        GeoJSON  TRUE
13       Geomedia FALSE
14         GeoRSS  TRUE
15            GML  TRUE
16            GMT  TRUE
17       GPSBabel  TRUE
18  GPSTrackMaker  TRUE
19            GPX  TRUE
20            HTF FALSE
21         Idrisi FALSE
22            KML  TRUE
23   MapInfo File  TRUE
24         Memory  TRUE
25   MSSQLSpatial  TRUE
26           ODBC  TRUE
27        OpenAir FALSE
28         PCIDSK  TRUE
29            PDS FALSE
30         PGDump  TRUE
31           PGeo FALSE
32            REC FALSE
33            S57  TRUE
34           SDTS FALSE
35       SEGUKOOA FALSE
36           SEGY FALSE
37            SUA FALSE
38            SVG FALSE
39          TIGER  TRUE
40        UK .NTF FALSE
41            VFK FALSE
42            VRT FALSE
43         XPlane FALSE
```

file.info gives:

```
 file.info(path="K:/2012 - IPD - Policy Maps/fe_2007_us_zcta500.zip/")
                                                             size isdir mode               mtime               ctime
    K:/2012 - IPD - Policy Maps/fe_2007_us_zcta500.zip/ 661131516 FALSE  666 2012-08-22 14:54:53 2012-08-22 14:50:43
                                                                      atime exe
    K:/2012 - IPD - Policy Maps/fe_2007_us_zcta500.zip/ 2012-08-22 14:58:38  no
```

Given the internet searches I've tried, it looks like I'm not the only one having this issue but I've been unable to find an answer. I'm not sure if the problem is related to the shapefile being inside a .zip folder or not. As it's a work computer, I have to wait for IT to install WinZip so that I can extract the shapefile and try outside a .zip folder. Hopefully that will be tomorrow.

Also, the package help states "Note that stray files in data source directories (such as *.dbf) may lead to suprious errors that accompanying *.shp are missing." The .zip folder has the following: a.dbf, b.prj, c.shp, d.shp.xml, e.shx.

Any help you can provide would be wonderful!
-Alex

Comment: Get a good unzip program like 7-zip, then you'll also be able to open .rar, .gz, .tar and so on.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should be able to unzip the files without the need of an external program with `unzip`. To read a shapefile with `readOGR`, the `dsn` is the directory name of where your 'unzipped' files are located, and `layer` is the name of your shape file without the extension. In the example below, replace myZIPmap with the appropriate shapefile name.

```
library(utils)
library(rgdal)

unzip("K:/2012 - IPD - Policy Maps/fe_2007_us_zcta500.zip")
zipmap <- readOGR(dsn = "K:/2012 - IPD - Policy Maps/fe_2007_us_zcta500", layer = "myZIPmap" )
```

Comment: unzip() worked as advertised. I should mention to anyone reading this to setwd() prior to unzip. I didn't and the unzip went to C:\my documents instead of the K:\ drive where I am working. 

However, Now I'm getting this error:

OGR data source with driver: ESRI Shapefile 
Source: "K:/2012 - IPD - Policy Maps/fe_2007_us_zcta500", layer: "fe_2007_us_zcta500"
with 33178 features and 4 fields
Feature type: wkbPolygon with 2 dimensions
Error: cannot allocate vector of size 307 Kb

Comment: Tested w/ a 2nd (smaller) shapefile--this time just 1 state instead of the whole USA and it worked as expected. Any help on memory allocation for the larger shapefile would still be helpful.

Comment: @Alex I'm not sure what the memory limits are for readOGR or why it's throwing this error, but a couple of alternatives to read shapefiles are `readShapePoly` in the `maptools` library or `read.shp` in the `fastshp`.  I had difficulty in trying the shape file with readOGR - maybe there's a topology error somewhere?