# Read shape file with readOGR verses readShapePoly

Tags: r, shapefile, rgdal

I have read a shapefile using `readShapePoly` in the `maptools` package, but cannot read that same file with `readOGR`.  I am hoping someone may be able to help me read the shapefile with `readOGR`.

I downloaded the file `orcounty.shp` from here: http://geography.uoregon.edu/geogr/topics/maps.htm

I also downloaded the associated files: `orcounty.shx`, `orcounty.sbx`, `orcounty.sbn`, and `orcounty.dbf` and put all five files in the folder: `c:/users/mark w miller/gis_in_R/shapefile_example/`

The following code reads the shapefile and displays some attributes:

```
library(maptools)

setwd('c:/users/mark w miller/gis_in_R/shapefile_example/')

# Oregon county census data (polygons)
orcounty.poly <- readShapePoly('orcounty.shp', proj4string=CRS("+proj=longlat"))
orcounty.line <- readShapeLines('orcounty.shp', proj4string=CRS("+proj=longlat"))

# see projection
summary(orcounty.poly)

Object of class SpatialPolygonsDataFrame
Coordinates:
         min        max
x -124.55840 -116.46944
y   41.98779   46.23626
Is projected: FALSE 
proj4string : [+proj=longlat]
Data attributes:
```

However, when I try to read that same shapefile using the following code I receive an error:

```
library(rgdal)

# read shapefile
oregon.map <- readOGR(dsn="c:/users/mark w miller/gis_in_R/shapefile_example/", layer="orcounty")

# convert to dataframe
oregon.map_df <- fortify(oregon.map)
```

The error message says:

```
Error in ogrInfo(dsn = dsn, layer = layer, encoding = encoding, use_iconv = use_iconv) : 
  Cannot open file
```

I can read Natural Earth http://www.naturalearthdata.com/ shapefiles using:

```
library(rgdal)

setwd("c:/users/mark w miller/gis_in_R/")

# read shapefile
wmap <- readOGR(dsn="ne_110m_physical", layer="ne_110m_land")
```

So, apparently there is a difference between the Natural Earth shapefiles and the Oregon shapefile `orcounty.shp`.

Thank you for any advice on how to read `orcounty.shp` with `readOGR`.  My question is similar to the question here: [rgdal / readOGR - unable to read shapefile from .zip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12082174/rgdal-readogr-unable-to-read-shapefile-from-zip)

Comment: I can open it normally. Try `readOGR(dsn = 'c:/users/mark w miller/gis_in_R/shapefile_example', layer = 'orcounty')`

Comment: @PauloCardoso That worked!  I cannot believe the solution was so simple.  If you want to post that as an answer I can accept it, or I could just delete the question.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Try to remove your last '/' from file path.

```
readOGR(dsn = 'c:/users/mark w miller/gis_in_R/shapefile_example',
        layer = 'orcounty')
```

Answer (score 3):

For anyone ending up here with this error on a Linux box, I found the problem was using a home path shortcut. i.e.

```
# Works
readOGR(dsn="/home/user/dir", layer="file")

# Doesn't work
readOGR(dsn="~/dir", layer="file")
```

I have no idea why.

Comment: The tilde expression (`~`) is usually expanded by the Unix shell. If you're passing it into an R library call, it will probably be read literally.

Comment: OK, thanks. Often it works in R, for reading files, setting working directories. In this instance it didn't.

Answer (score 1):

I used the file ne_110m_land

Try with this:

```
setwd('D:/JMSR/codes.R/mapas')
unzip("ne_110m_land.zip")
ogrInfo(".", "ne_110m_land")
wmap <- readOGR(".", "ne_110m_land")
```

Answer (score 0):

`raster::shapefile` wraps around `readOGR` to take care of paths and tildes; just pass the full file name.

```
 library(raster)
 x <- shapefile("c:/users/orcounty.shp')
```

or

```
 y <- shapefile("~/users/orcounty.shp")
```