# In the tmaptools package, read_shape yields "layer not found" error

Tags: r, gis, tmap

I've used the `read_shape()` function from the `tmaptools` package to import shapefiles many times successfully, but I've now encountered a strange error.

For some shapefiles the `read_shape()` command yields message:

> "Error in ogrInfo(dsn = dsn, layer = layer, encoding = encoding, use_iconv = use_iconv,  : Layer not found"

For other shapefiles, I have no problem at all. Here is an example of an open data shapefile for which I am getting this error: https://opendata.arcgis.com/datasets/3605212dc7f0477cacb4cca884487e3d_0.zip?outSR=%7B%22wkid%22%3A32054%2C%22latestWkid%22%3A32054%7D

I believe the error may be related to the tmap package because I am able to open the shapefiles in question with no issues in QGIS. I'm running the current versions of RStudio, tmap, and tmaptools.

Any ideas?

Comment: The error is a common one with `rgdal::readOGR()` (which is actually what's loading the shapefile; `tmaptools::read_shape()` is just a wrapper). Often it's because the `dsn` (i.e. the directory) argument is incorrectly specified. [This](http://zevross.com/blog/2016/01/13/tips-for-reading-spatial-files-into-r-with-rgdal/) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22289794/read-shape-file-with-readogr-verses-readshapepoly) might help.

Comment: Thanks to @Phil for pointing me on the right track.

`tmaptools::read_shape()` is sometimes confused when the name of the directory storing the .shp file and its companion files is located. By leaving the name of the folder unchanged, this error is avoided.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After experiencing this error in multiple situations, I've found that the only consistent fix is to use a different tool.

Now I use the "shapefile" command from the raster package.

So,

```
 #install.packages("raster")
 library(raster)
 shapefile("~/YOURFILEPATHHERE")
```

This will read the shapefile into your session as a SpatialPolygonsDataFrame, which can then be used by the tmap (or similar) package.